# How to export data frame with vector entries into CSV file?

Tags: r, dataframe, export-to-csv, jsonlite

I have a data frame with some entries as lists. This was an import from a JSON file, where an entry might have multiple tags. It imported JSON file using `jsonlite` package with `flatten=TRUE`. An example entry from my tags column is:

```
list(tag = c("ethicaltheory", "gametheory"), raw_tag = c("ethical heory", "Game Theory"))
```

I filtered the table down and want to export it to a csv. When I tried the `write.csv` command, I hit an error when it hit the first entry with `list`:

> "unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'"

The question is can I export this file as is, did I make a mistake in importing it?

I'd be fine with converting entries to strings or something, but I'm not sure how to do that for the entire table.

Comment: What exactly do you want the output file to look like? CSV files expect to have each column be a single value and every row to have the same number of columns. How many columns have multiple values? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I'd be fine with the tag column having each entry literally just be "list(tag = c("ethicaltheory", "gametheory"), raw_tag = c("ethical theory", "Game Theory"))" etc. I'll append my entry with an example.

Comment: OK. But you are going to have a heck of a time reading that back into R because that's certainly not a "normal" CSV file. Are you sure you really need CSV? What if you stored it in a binary format that R can more easily read?

Comment: I wanted something I could share with people who don't know R. Actually, I couldn't create an example, because R won't let me do what the read_json command did from scratch.

Comment: I think I figured out a fix assets_refined <- data.frame(lapply(assets_filtered_more, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: Ugly, But I think it works. Where assets_filtered_more was my filtered dataframe from the original assets that jsonlite read in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. I did not know that `data.frame` can store `list`. This algorithm is taking variable length `list` stored in a row of a `data.frame`. Then it finds maximum length, create `matrix` with proper dimensions then it saves the file.

```
x <- list(tag = letters[1:2], raw_tag = letters[1:3])
y <- list(tag = letters[1:2], raw_tag = letters[1:2])
z <- list(tag = letters[1:3], raw_tag = letters[1:4])
df <- data.frame(clmn = I(list(x, y, z)))

r <- apply(df, 1, unlist)
lm <- max(unlist(lapply(r, length)))

df <- data.frame(
  matrix(
    rep(0, (lm * nrow(df))),
    ncol = lm
    )
  )
)

vals.v <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  v <- unlist(r[i])
  l <- length(v)
  c(v, rep(0, lm - l))
}))
fin.res <- t(matrix(vals.v, ncol = nrow(df)))

# write.csv(fin.res, "res2.csv") # uncomment to save CSV file
```

Comment: I didn't either. I've played around with it, but it's hard to reproduce from scratch. Somehow the json reader knew how.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, in terms of expanding out that sub-list